# Foreach to find the subordinates of my subordinates and so on

Tags: c#-3.0, foreach

I need to do a foreach to find all my subordinates and that includes to find all of the subordinates of my subordinates and so on...

I was trying to accomplish but I couldn't pass to find the 2nd level of subordinates...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSUDO:

```
  private List<Subordinate> GetSubordinates(Subordinate you){
        List<Subordinate> subs = new List<Subordinate>();
        if(!you.HasSubordinates){
              return subs;
         }

         foreach(Subordinate s in you.Subordinates){
            subs.AddRange(GetSubordinates(s));
        }
  }
```

Comment: So many levels?  It looks almost like yours (with out the yield) or base case?  Did what am I looking over?

Comment: I'll name some.  First, "Subordinates" what is that?  It implies a collection, but you treat it as an individual.  Second, the choice of accumulating over yielding.  Third, the empty check which is not necessary....

Comment: Easy killer remember the PSUDO tag.  The first was a typo... which i fixed, Second you are correct which i already noted above, and third the empty check is only not necessary if you assume Subordinates is non null.  If the Subordinates property is nullable then it would be *very* necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
private IEnumerable<Employee> RecursiveGet(Employee durr)
{
  foreach(var sub in durr.Subordinates)
  {
    yield return sub;
    foreach(var recurse in RecursiveGet(sub))
      yield return recurse;
  }
}
```

Comment: I might change this to be an extension rather than a method.  Also, this would be a lot of fun if C# allowed yields in lambda's/anonymous methods.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use [recursion](http://www.functionx.com/csharp/fundamentals/recursion.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
object RecursiveCall(Collection collection, object itemToFind)
{
    foreach(var item in collection)
    {
        if(item == itemToFind)
        {
             return item;
        }
        else
        {
             RecursiveCall(item, itemToFind);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He isn't looking for a subordinate, he's trying to collapse all subordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Go for an implementation of recursive technique for this.